# How to export multiple records into multiple files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns in a table. One is the file name and other is message.

I have to export all the records to different text files, each message in one file.

For example, I have 10 records in the table, so I need to create 10 files. Is it possible to do in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have SSIS then it's pretty easy.  If not, it's possible, but not pretty and you're better off doing something like this in a higher application tier.  Please add more detail to your question so we can know better what your environment is and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Tables don't have "records" they have rows and columns

Comment: You can create a script in any language or shell you want to retrieve the data and write it to files. SQL is meant for data manipulation, not file management. It's a lot easier to manage and write files in a shell script. Eg, in Powershell you could use [Read-SqlTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) to read all data and then use a `foreach` loop to write whatever you want out

Comment: Hi Hiren Desai, Solution provided by you is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible...
There are two ways -

1. Do it using T-SQL
2. Use some programming language such as C# or Java or PHP

Since the question is more related to database, I will assume and go with option-1.

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR;
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR;
DECLARE @FileContent VARCHAR;

DECLARE CUR_RECORDS CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT FileName, Message
    FROM   Your_Table;

OPEN CUR_RECORDS
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_RECORDS INTO @FileName, @Message

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   @FileContent= @FileContent + @FileName + ',' + @Message + '\n';

   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_RECORDS INTO @FileName, @Message
END
CLOSE CUR_RECORDS
DEALLOCATE CUR_RECORDS
GO

EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  'echo ' + @FileContent + ' > C:\AppTextFile.txt'
```

The exact logic of how many file and how many records per file can be decided by you.

Comment: Weakening security just to run a shell script is a very bad idea. `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default, for decades, for some *very* good reasons. It's actually a lot easier and safer to do it the other way around - have a shell script call SQL Server eg with `sqlcmd`, `bcp` or one of the Powershell comands. execute a query and export the data as needed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The answer begins with two options, seems you missed to read the #2.

Comment: Remove the glaring security whole then. This shouldn't be posted as an option at all, not for such a simple case. You have to actually *work* to weaken security and use `xp_cmdshell`. This isn't an accidental suggestion

Comment: Never mind the truncated filenames and messages because `varchar` doesn't have a length

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Let the author decide how is it effecting his/her security.. He might be using it for his local computer. If he's using for production, he won't be able to anyway since the author may not have access to enable it..

Assuming everything is a security breach is also a breach to information.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - BTW You are welcome to suggest an Answer which is better than above. (That's whole the purpose of this platform :))